# ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompatibleBrokerVersion' from 'kafka.errors'

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to import:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
```

but I am getting this error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompatibleBrokerVersion' from
> 'kafka.errors'.

I have made sure to install kafka-python instead of kafka, and have pip uninstalled kafka. I also did not name any files kafka.py, although one does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same error.
I have repeated on my local end too with only "from kafka.errors import IncompatibleBrokerVersion".
The solution seems pretty simple after many failed tries:

```
pip uninstall kafka kafka-python
pip install git+https://github.com/wbarnha/kafka-python-ng.git
```